# Passing argument(s) to a module private function/sub

Tags: vba

I am trying to pass two numbers to a module private function and return the value as a sum.

```vb
'In Module1
Private Function xSum(x As Double, y As Double) As Double
  xSum = x + y
End Function
```

```vb
'In Module2
Private Sub PrintSum()
  Debug.Print "Sum is: " & xSum(5, 5) 'Expected results 10
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks BigBen. I wanted to keep all private in separate modules.

Answer (score 2):

It is **not** a good idea to call private functions from outside their scope, because they are private for a reason, and the reason is not to be called from anywhere, but from the specific module in which they reside.

Anyway, for any other reasons, `Application.Run` would work the expected way:

```
Private Sub PrintSum()
    Debug.Print "Sum is: " & Application.Run("Modul1.xSum", 5, 5)
End Sub
```

The name of the function is in inverted commas and the arguments are separated by a comma:

[image]

Comment: I want to keep all private but this' exactly what i want - Application.Run("Modul1.xSum", 5, 5). Thanks Vityata

Comment: @Joel - you probably have your own reasons to do it this way, I guess. Glad I could help :)

Comment: @Joel this is absolutely NOT what you want. `Private` members are meant to be invoked from the module they live in, full stop. Consider WHY you think you want private procedures, and whether `Option Private Module` can achieve that without making all your procedure calls late-bound and stringified.

Comment: If you truly need this function to be private, then you could have a copy of it in both modules. Due to scope, you won't have issues having the same function names.